# Stream and filter for structure of Lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Trying to get list of items from structure and avoid lot of for cycles and ifs, so I wanna use `Stream`

For example, lets have a following structure:

```
class House {
List<Family> familyList;
}

class Family {
List<Person> personList;
String someInfo;

}

class Person {
String name;
int age;
List<Item> itemList;
}

class Item{
String name;    
}
```

I want to create:

1. `List<Item>` from families
2. `List<Item>` from families filtered by name
3. List`from house, which contain only records filtered by`Item`name

so far I tried the following:

1. List testItems = house1.familyList.stream().flatMap(f -> f.personList.stream().flatMap(p ->p.itemList.stream()))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());
   List testItems = house1.familyList.stream().flatMap(f -> f.personList.stream()).flatMap(p->p.itemList.stream())
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
2. List testItemsFiltered= house1.familyList.stream().flatMap(f -> f.personList.stream().flatMap(p ->p.itemList.stream().filter(item->item.name.equals("Hammer"))))
       .collect(Collectors.toList());

but both are throwing nullpointers

for 3. variant I have no idea so far

kevin edit:
check: familiList contains few `Item` with names - "item1","item2","item3"

```
List<Family> filteredFamilies = house1.familyList.stream()
                .filter(f -> f.personList.stream()
                        .anyMatch(p ->p.itemList.stream()
                                .anyMatch(i -> i.name.equals("item1"))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (Family family : filteredFamilies) {
            for (Person p : family.personList) {
                for (Item i : p.itemList) {
                    System.out.println(i.name);
                }
            }
        }
```

results:

```
item1
item2
item2
item3
item1
item2
item2
item3
```

befor filtering:

f1-
   _p1- it1,it2
   _p2- it2,it3,it4
f2
  _p3- it1,i2
  _p4  i3
f3
  _p5  i5

after filter:

f1-
  p1- it1
f2
  p3- it1

Comment: Are your lists empty or null?

Comment: .. I forgot to assign list to Person object, but still have no idea about 3. point

Comment: The question is, does those families have persons which contain these items? Normally you should check the other way around. Create a family whit persons which do not have item1 in it and then check if `filteredFamilies` does contain those

Comment: because your check does display all items of the persons, but your question was that you want the families where a person has the item `item1`.

Comment: I wasn't specific sry, I want all families where person will have only items with specific name, so the output should be only "item1", all other items will be filtred, is this possible?

Comment: Do you want to filter the items or the families. I think the families am i right?

Comment: I changed the answer according to the new question from you.

Comment: check example of expectation

Comment: Then you have to add also a remove logic after filtering.

Comment: The problem is, that the `persons` lists from the `Family` has to be adapted and therefore a new list has to be created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried the first code:

```
List<Item> testItems = house1.familyList.stream()
               .flatMap(f -> f.personList.stream()
                   .flatMap(p ->p.itemList.stream()))
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and this code works. It seems that you don't initialize the lists at the beginning. So i would suggest to init them in the constructor and the `NullPointer` should disappear. Also when the lists are empty no `NullPointer` appears.

This code should return each `family` which has a `person` with a specific `item`:

```
String expectedItem = "test";
List<Family> families = house1.familyList.stream()
                .filter(f -> f.personList.stream()
                        .anyMatch(p ->p.itemList.stream()
                                .anyMatch(i -> i.name.equals(expectedItem))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

According to the question the answer has also be changed:

```
String expectedItem = "test";
List<Family> families = house1.familyList.stream()
                .filter(f -> f.personList.stream()
                        .anyMatch(p ->p.itemList.stream()
                                .allMatch(i -> i.name.equals(expectedItem))))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: when i tried it, it contained all items, not just expected, does it work for you?

Comment: i tried it and it worked. The question is, do they reference the same `item` with the same `name`?